# SQL Server 2008 r2 - T-SQL LIKE or PATINDEX to match characters OTHER than A-Z, 0-9, hyphen, period, underscore and tilde

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pattern-matching, user-defined-functions

Please help me write a PATINDEX or LIKE statement to match characters **other** than:

- A-Z, 0-9, hyphen (-), period (.), underscore (_), and tilde (~)

I plan to use this in a scalar UDF with an nvarchar(200) input, which processes the input by:

1. Replace the non-matching characters with hyphen (-)
2. Replace two occurences of hyphen (--) with single (-)
3. Removes leading and trailing hypens (-)
4. Returns the processed input

This will be used to create part of an SEO-friendly URL e.g. `/my-seo-friendly-url-1`. I am very confident in doing this UDF, apart from the pattern-matching part. Regex-like stuff confuses me! Please help.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably best done in your application but

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^-a-zA-Z0-9.~_]%', @YourString COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)
```

should do it in TSQL

Comment: Stupid question but are the % needed?

Comment: @ChrisCannon - Not if you are only processing a single character at a time. Yes if you are trying to find the first character in a string containing more than one character.

Comment: It was a stupid question sorry, here's another: if I omit the COLLATE can I omit the A-Z

Comment: @ChrisCannon - You mean and just use `a-z` instead of having both? Depends on your default database collation. If you have a case sensitive or binary collation by default then you will get wrong results hence me specifying a collation explicitly.

Comment: My database is not case-sensitive, I know this because `SELECT 1 WHERE 'abc' = 'ABC';` returns 1?

Comment: @ChrisCannon - You still need to use binary collation and the pattern in my answer regardless actually. Under `Latin1_General_CS_AS` for example the following letters are in the range `a-z`. `a,A,ª,á,Á,à,À,â,Â,ä,Ä,ã,Ã,å,Å,æ,Æ,b,B,c,C,ç,Ç,d,D,ð,Ð,e,E,é,É,è,È,ê,Ê,ë,Ë,f,F,ƒ,g,G,h,H,i,I,í,Í,ì,Ì,î,Î,ï,Ï,j,J,k,K,l,L,m,M,n,N,ñ,Ñ,o,O,º,ó,Ó,ò,Ò,ô,Ô,ö,Ö,õ,Õ,ø,Ø,œ,Œ,p,P,q,Q,r,R,s,S,š,Š,ß,t,T,þ,Þ,™,u,U,ú,Ú,ù,Ù,û,Û,ü,Ü,v,V,w,W,x,X,y,Y,ý,Ý,ÿ,Ÿ,z`

Comment: Ok thanks very much for your help, final question does the underscore in `'%[^a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]%'` need to be escaped? If not how come?

Comment: @ChrisCannon - It already is in square brackets, which can be used to escape "special" characters as well as the `ESCAPE` keyword as per [the docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx). You need to make sure that `-` is at the end of the square bracketed set though as otherwise that will be interpreted as denoting a range of characters.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. You're certainly an expert!

Comment: Ahhh... another question... sorry... Do I need to do a `SELECT` or can I do the `COLLATE` in a `SET` statement like `SET @i = PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]%', @DirtyUriPart COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN);` thanks